# Acumatica Fields from INSiteStatus do not show in search after adding to InventoryItem NoteID

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add some Qty fields from `INSiteStatus` to the universal search results for `InventoryItem` entries.  Instead of clicking into the item, we want to save a click and see the info in the search results.

I added the join and the fields to the `NoteID` (code below) and everything published fine.  I tried searching for a stock item and the results for the `InventoryItem` fields are displayed, but the `INSiteStatus` fields are skipped.

How do I get the `INSiteStatus` fields to display?

**Code :**

```
[PXSearchable(SM.SearchCategory.IN, "{0}: {1}", new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.itemType), typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
   new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr) },
NumberFields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
Line1Format = "{0}{1}", Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr),typeof(INSiteStatus.qtyOnHand)},
Line2Format = "{0}{1}{2}", Line2Fields = new Type[] { typeof(InventoryItem.descr),typeof(INSiteStatus.lastModifiedDateTime),typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD)},
WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<InventoryItem.itemStatus>, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>),
MatchWithJoin = typeof(InnerJoin<INSiteStatus, On<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>),
SelectForFastIndexing = typeof(Select2<InventoryItem, InnerJoin<INSiteStatus, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>>>)
 )]
[PXNote]
```

Results from searching...

```
Finished Good: SLBV4-CO1-DEL

Description: Intel Xeon E5620 2.4/12M/1066 4C 80W

Description: Intel Xeon E5620 2.4/12M/1066 4C 80W - Inventory ID: SLBV4-CO1-DEL
```

Comment: UPDATE: I came back to my test site after letting it sit overnight and I am now able to see the lastmodifieddate, but not the qtyOnHand field.  Unfortunately, the qtyOnHand field is the one I really want to see.  I tried joining INItemStats and found similar results - I could see the valMethod field, but not qtyOnHand or any of the cost fields.

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up creating a ticket with Acumatica.  It turns out that you can display decimal fields but only for the primary DAC and not the Joined DACs.  This is a limitation.